# Modules don't appear on contact page [Joomla 3.6.4]

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I am currently making a template for Joomla on my localhost webserver and I
am now making the contact page but I've run into a nasty problem. The issue is that modules won't appear on this page which is weird. I have never had this before and I have no clue where to look or what to do. I tried Googling but no real solutions.

What I've tried:

- Removing and creating a new menu page
- Triple checking if module is assigned to the contact page
- Assigning the same module to another page and check if it appeared on that page and yes it did
- Clean the cache

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: Have you set the permissions to "public" for the modules? Does the contact page have a different template assigned to it?

Comment: @Lodder What permission do I need to set? I see Delete, Edit, Edit State and Frontend Editing. Where can I check what template page is assigned?

Comment: @Lodder I got it, I had a comment line in my index.php and I forgot to close the statement which rendered the position tags as comment. It works now!

Comment: ah fair enough :) good find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I feel so stupid right now... I had a comment line in my index.php and I forgot to close the statement which rendered the position tags as comment. It works now!